# IIS website hostname accessible locally but not on LAN

Tags: iis, dns

The goal here is to set up a hostednetwork wifi on a server (fake server, it's Windows 10 x64), the client connect to this wifi, then connect to the website on the server. This is done by creating the hostednetwork :

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=BORNE-1234 key=12345678`

`netsh wlan start hostednetwork`

IIS is configured with a simple website in it. And I just tried every bindings possible :

```
http  borne.fr       80   *
http  borne.fr       80   192.168.137.1
http  (Empty)        80   192.168.137.1
http  www.borne.fr   80   *
http  www.borne.fr   80   192.168.137.1
```

Then i edit the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file to add this line :
`192.168.137.1 borne.fr www.borne.fr`

I even tried with 127.0.0.1 but nothing works. On a browser on the server, `borne.fr` works. But if I connect to the created wifi with another machine `borne.fr` give the error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED whereas with the IP address it works. I tried everything mentioned here https://serverfault.com/a/452269.

I also added an exception on the firewall (in and out) for port 80.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: "Then i edit the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file to add this line". That's it. Your changes there only apply to that machine, but not any other machine. Try to set up a DNS server please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also set "192.168.137.1 borne.fr www.borne.fr" on another machine.

If "192.168.137.1 borne.fr www.borne.fr" is not set on another computer, it will not know what the IP address of [www.borne.fr](http://www.borne.fr) is.

Hosts files were used to resolve hosts names before DNS. hosts files would be massive documents used to aide the network name resolution.

If you have a DNS server in your LAN, you can configure the DNS server to resolve [www.borne.fr](http://www.borne.fr) to 192.168.137.1.

Comment: Ok so I missunderstood how hosts file works. Users that will connect to the borne are only smartphones and shouldn't do anything more than connecting to wifi. So I have to setup a DNS server. After some searches on internet, it doesn't seem easy to setup on windows 10. Any recommandations ?

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323380/how-to-configure-dns-for-internet-access-in-windows-server-2003

Comment: This is for windows server. There's not this component on Windows 10 unfortunatly.